# Disconnected features in Python, QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, network, geometric-network

I'm working with code from the [Disconnected Islands](https://github.com/AfriGIS-South-Africa/disconnected-islands) plugin in QGIS x64 and Python. Normally, the plugin ends by writing the FID of features to a CSV and their corresponding network group ID.

Instead, I would like to be able to find all the network groups with only one feature (= lines with no connections). I'm not sure how to proceed.

Preferably, I would like to be able to do what ArcGIS's [Find Disconnected Features in Geometric Network](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/find-disconnected-features-in-geometric-network.htm) tool does, but I need to use QGIS.

```
# get the network
layer = iface.activeLayer()
G = nx.Graph()

# construct graph
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    line = feat.geometry().asPolyline()
    for i in range(len(line)-1):
        G.add_edges_from([((line[i][0], line[i][1]), (line[i+1][0], line[i+1][1]), 
                          {'fid': feat.id()})])

# evaluate on connected components
connected_components = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G))

# gather edges and components to which they belong
fid_comp = {}
for i, graph in enumerate(connected_components):
   for edge in graph.edges_iter(data=True):
       fid_comp[edge[2].get('fid', None)] = i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested the plugin code but, assuming you end up with a dictionary containing feature id as key and component id as value, something like:

```
fid_comp = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 5}
```

The problem becomes one of simply extracting the feature ids that have a unique value in the dictionary (i.e. they don't share their component id value with any other feature).

Try something like this:

```
countMap = {}
for v in fid_comp.values():
    countMap[v] = countMap.get(v,0) + 1
isolated = [k for k, v in fid_comp.items() if countMap[v] == 1]
layer.selectByIds(isolated)
```

This should select all your disconnected features, which you could then save as a new layer if you wish.