# Geometric networks (networkx) in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, geometric-network

I'm working with code from the [Disconnected Islands plugin](https://github.com/AfriGIS-South-Africa/disconnected-islands/blob/master/disconnected_islands.py) in QGIS x64 and Python 3. Normally, the plugin uses networkx to create a geometric network and ends by writing the FID of features with no connections to a CSV and their corresponding network group ID.

I'm not familiar with network theory/geometric networks, so I'm not sure if this is possible: is there a way to return the fid of segments with only one connection? If so, which part of the code should I change?

```
# get the network
layer = iface.activeLayer()
G = nx.Graph()

# construct graph
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    line = feat.geometry().asPolyline()
    for i in range(len(line)-1):
        G.add_edges_from([((line[i][0], line[i][1]), (line[i+1][0], line[i+1][1]), 
                          {'fid': feat.id()})])

# evaluate on connected components
connected_components = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G))

# gather edges and components to which they belong
fid_comp = {}
for i, graph in enumerate(connected_components):
   for edge in graph.edges_iter(data=True):
       fid_comp[edge[2].get('fid', None)] = i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is very similar to your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309402/disconnected-features-in-python-qgis).

Only now, instead of finding isolated features (1 feature in a network group), you want to find features with only one connection (2 features in a network group).

You should be able to adapt my answer from the previous question.

Having established that `fid_comp` is a dictionary containing **feature id** as **key** and **component id** as **value**, you want to find all the keys which each have exactly one duplicate value.

Assuming that a small example of the `fid_comp` dictionary might look something like this:

```
fid_comp = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 5, 11: 6, 12: 6}
```

Try this:

```
countMap = {}
for v in fid_comp.values():
    countMap[v] = countMap.get(v,0) + 1
pairs = [k for k, v in fid_comp.items() if countMap[v] == 2]
#select features if desired
layer.selectByIds(pairs)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand the code/theory itself much better now :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.