# Find lines not related to any other lines

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, select-by-location, spatial-relationship

I have a pipes layer. I need query all dangling pipes, it isn't relationship any other pipes. I have attach image. Is there any method to do this?[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis/305193#305193), find a required argument and apply it as `METHOD` in the code from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168689/how-to-use-qgisselectbylocation-in-pyqgis/168698)

Comment: By the way mentioning *'pygis'* tag and not providing a sample of your code reduces chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Otherwise the most common *"Select by location"* should do the job

Comment: @Taras thanks I will try

Comment: This might also help you (seems very similar to what you are trying to do) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309402/disconnected-features-in-python-qgis